# React - return few rows of table and REACTDOM error

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm having trouble creating/returning multiple rows in React. There's an error when returning two rows: `<tr> can't be a child of <tr>`.

### [My Current Code](http://pastebin.com/E4CszVXj)

I'm creating a simple calendar, so far I have a header that includes the days of the week from Monday - Sunday.  I want:

- the body to have 4-5 rows (one for every week)
- to apply this weeks (rather than 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 etc the array from the top of the page - map data from API - firstWeek, secondWeek etc)

The calendar for the whole month should look like the following from the first element to the last one(7):

```
firstWeek[0], firstWeek[1], firstWeek[2] etc etc
[secondWeek[0], secondWeek[1] etc etc
thirdWeek[0], secondWeek[1] etc etc
```

I thought about using a loop, but am not sure how to approach it -- should I use something else? Before I fix my design pattern, I have to fix those DOM Errors when returning a few rows.

---

And yes, I know this is a codesmell, but have no idea how to return it diffrent:

```
  var firstWeek = days[0].map(day=>day.day_number);
  var secondWeek = days[1].map(day=>day.day_number);
  var thirdWeek = days[2].map(day=>day.day_number);
  var forthWeek = days[3].map(day=>day.day_number);
  var fifthWeek = days[4].map(day=>day.day_number);
```

Comment: Can you please show the exact error?

Comment: Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <tr>. See CalendarList > tr > tr. The error in case then i add another <tr> to create new ROW.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to nest a table row as a child of another table row, which is invalid HTML. Check out my answer for an example to properly rendering a table, and see if it helps you get the right result.

Comment: I understand it's hard to communicate when you speak a different language.  I tried cleaning up some of the English, but I'm still confused on some of what you're saying; especially, regarding the numbers and the weeks — the second bullet point.

Comment: Sorry for mistakes. I will try to provide the best question as I can in future.
The second bullet point is to try return some data from API. Now I return manually the data (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), but I wanted Data from API response.
I am trying to resolve it in that way, which offer Boris Ablamunits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is warning you that you are trying to nest a table row `<tr>` as a child of another table row, which is invalid HTML.

What you want to do, is map every week of the month to its own row, where each row displays its own data. Then, render the set of rows properly within a table. Something like this:

```
    const tableRows = weeks.map((week) => {
       return (
           <tr>
               { week.map(dayOfWeek => <td>{ dayOfWeek.someData }</td>) }
           </tr>
       );
    });

    return <table><tbody>{ tableRows }</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Thank you for clue. Now, I also refactor my code with this code smells.
It is because I didn't be sure I can mix also with <tr> and <td> within map function, now it is working properly and see where was the bug. In future I will remember to generate the rows in JS.